# In Debian, where in the filesystem would a daemon provide dynamic measurement results?

Tags: linux, debian, daemon, fhs

For a diploma thesis, I am developing a Linux daemon that runs on Debian and is also Debian-packaged for easy administration. It reads various measurement results via I²C. The results shall be shown on a website.

In Debian, where in the filesystem would a daemon output such measurement data to be updated regularly and read from other applications or the user? To clearify, logging is done seperately, I would just have a few files containing the current values (just like you can read the CPU temperature in /proc).

From the [FHS](http://refspecs.linuxfoundation.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html), these seem to be most fitting:

- `/var/lib` or `/var/spool`
- `/srv`
- `/tmp`

Where should it go?

Comment: In your case I would use /var/lib

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`/var` is structure for variable file. So keep it in `/var/lib/you_application/`